# Laravel Socialite Facebook login not working ( AuthController does not exist )

Tags: laravel

I am trying to include Facebook login in my project but I get error AuthController.php does not exist, can anyone please help me with the solution or what the mistake I did?

config/services.php

```
'facebook' => [
    'client_id' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID'),
    'client_secret' => env('FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET'),
    'redirect' => 'https://www.sehhaty.so/login/facebook/callback',
],
```

.env

```
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_ID=MY_FACEBOOK_APP_ID
FACEBOOK_CLIENT_SECRET=MY_FACEBOOK_SECRET
```

web.php

```
Route::get('login/facebook', 'App\Http\Controller\AuthController@redirectToProviderFacebook')->name('auth.facebook.redirect');
Route::get('login/facebook/callback', 'App\Http\Controller\AuthController@handleProviderCallbackFacebook')->name('auth.facebook.callback');
```

AuthController.php

```
public function redirectToProviderFacebook()
{
    return Socialite::driver('facebook')->redirect();
}

public function handleProviderCallbackFacebook()
{
    $user = Socialite::driver('facebook')->user();

    $email = $user->email;
    $db_user = User::where('email', '=', $email)->first();

    if ($db_user == null) {
        $registerd_user = User::create(['name' => $user->nickname, 'phone' => '01029360040', 'email' => $user->email, 'password' => Hash::make('12345678'), 'oauth_token' => $user->token]);
        Auth::login($registerd_user);
    } else {
        Auth::login($db_user);
    }

    return redirect(route('home'));
}
```

the error

[image: The Error]

Comment: Did you delete the default `AuthController` controller?

Comment: no I keep it and it icludes the other login standard ways and works well

Comment: which laravel version are you using?

Comment: the latest version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Namespace for your controller will be `App\Http\Controllers\AuthController` and not `App\Http\Controller\AuthController`, you are missing letter `s` in the word **Controller**.

By the way you can uncomment `$namespace` in **RouteServiceProvider** and then you don't have to write a full namespace:

https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/upgrade#automatic-controller-namespace-prefixing

```
Route::get('login/facebook', 'AuthController@redirectToProviderFacebook')->name('auth.facebook.redirect');
```

Comment: hey my friend it worked but i have another issue, when any user else try to login using facebbok it says that they must create facebook developer app, how can i fix this?

Comment: You will have to create a facebook developer app, you have to register some kind of "app" for every platform(facebook/google) to use oauth